# How to display Firestore data on Chart.js in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, chart.js, visualization

In my angular project, I save the data in firestore collection and would like to display them in 'Line Chart' of Chart.js.How do I achieve this? Following is the component file that creates the lin chart from the values hard coded.

```
  createChart(){      
    this.chart = new Chart("MyChart", {
      type: 'line', //this denotes tha type of chart    
      data: {// values on X-Axis
        labels: ['2022-05-10', '2022-05-11', '2022-05-12'], 
           datasets: [
          {
            label: "Weight",
            data: ['100','95', '80'],
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
          },            
        ]
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio:2.5
      }          
    });
  }
```